# How can I install Java Editor

Tags: 14.04, wine, java, ide, editor

I want to install [this Java Editor](http://javaeditor.org/doku.php) in Ubuntu 14.04.

I have already install Wine1.7 and Java 8. :)

How can I do this?

(Sorry, I am a Ubuntu-beginner)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Download a JDK - Java Development Kit from Oracle for Windows.
   Choose 32bit or 64bit like the same as you use in wine. Please use
   version 7 of this JDK. The setup file first letters are jdk-7. The
   version jdk-8xx will crash during installation.
2. Install it into your wine environment.
3. Download Java-Editor.
4. Install it to your wine environment by running the setup file
   (JavaEditorxx.xxSetup.exe where xx.xx is the version you'd
   downloaded). Java-Editor will recognize an installed JDK by itself.
   If you like you may download and install additional tools from
   [Java-Editors webpage](http://www.javaeditor.org/doku.php?id=en:download#other).

But I wonder why you'd need to use Java Editor when we can have better cross-platform IDEs like Netbeans, IDEA, jCreator or a text editor like vim.